# Only past in rows with certain value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to learn SQL but it's not easy :D

Well I need code to look for Value1.

If value 1 is present, then store value2 into column X.

For example:

Table 1:

| ID | FIRST-NAME | LAST-NAME | PLACE | AGE | DO LIKE CAKE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Allan | Jakobsen | Germany | 25 | NULL |
| 2 | benny | Jakobsen | Denmark | 65 | NULL |
| 3 | benny | buller | Sweden | 30 | NULL |

And so on

Table 2

| ID | Cars | CarType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mondeo | Ford |
| 2 | 106 | peugeot |
| 1 | lada | russian |

and so on

Table 3

| Stores | Cash |
| --- | --- |
| Store-1 | 500$ |
| Store-2 | 200$ |

So tables 1 and 2 have the trigger key `[ID]`, and table 1 has a column `[DO LIKE CAKE]` but table 2 doesn't.

I want every table with a `[ID]` column and I want to have `[DO LIKE CAKE]` . I think this is code in itself :)

Then if value `[ID]` is present, then paste value 2 in `[DO LIKE CAKE]` all over the tables :) So it looks for the id in table 1 2 3 but only sees it in table 1 and 2 but not 3 :D

Hope this makes sense.

Well not much I'm not the best in SQL coding :D

Comment: What precisely is your question? Please read [ask] ***and*** [mre] ***and*** [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to help you out, because it seems like you're new to this.
First, in the future, please post sample data formatted in a way that it's easy for people to generate a query. I've taken the liberty of creating this for you in table variables like so:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(50), LastName VARCHAR(50), Place VARCHAR(50), Age TINYINT, DoLikeCake BIT DEFAULT(NULL))
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1,'Allan','Jakobsen','Germany',25,NULL)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (2,'benny','Jakobsen','Denmark',65,NULL)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (3,'benny','buller','Sweden',30,NULL)


DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT, CarModel VARCHAR(50), CarType VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1,'mondeo','Ford')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(2,'106','peugeot')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1,'lada','russian')

DECLARE @Table3 TABLE (StoreName VARCHAR(50),Cash MONEY)
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES ('Store-1',500)
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES ('Store-2',200)
```

Second, I'm not sure what you are looking for in a query. Table three has no common columns, so there's no way to join it to the main query. I'm not sure what you mean by "paste DO LIKE CAKE everywhere", but your query has multiple rows in Table2 that match to rows in Table1. This will cause duplication, unless the data is aggregated in some way.

Take a look at this sample code. I think it's what you're after, but even if not, you should be able to figure out the general concept and move things around.

If you're looking for something else, please clarify your question and respond.

```
SELECT  t.ID
        ,t.FirstName
        ,t.LastName
        ,t.Place
        ,t.Age
        ,t.DoLikeCake
        ,STRING_AGG(t2.CarType, ',') AS CarTypes
        ,STRING_AGG(t2.CarModel, ',') AS CarModels
FROM    @Table1 AS t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table2 AS t2 ON t2.ID = t.ID
GROUP BY
        t.ID
        ,t.FirstName
        ,t.LastName
        ,t.Place
        ,t.Age
        ,t.DoLikeCake;
```